# Need Help with Custom Controller & VF Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

Can anyone provide insight into what I need to do to prevent my page from displaying Territories that return zero results?

They are currently showing because I made a list and my VF page loops through all “Close Date (Forecasted)” fields  in the list using apex:repeat. Then an inner apex:repeat loops through all territories in the territory list.

The problem is that there are not always opportunities that are in both lists.

```
******** CONTROLLER *******
```

```
public class ForecastController {

    public List<Opportunity> opportunities {get;set;}
    public String[] closeDates {get;set;}
    public String[] terrs {get;set;}


    public void load(){

        Opportunities = [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Account.Territory_Manager__c, StageName, CloseDate, Forecastable__c, 
                         Forecasted_Close_Date_30_60_90__c, Close_Month_Forecasted__c, Account.Terr_From_Zip__c, 
                         (Select Id, Account_Name__c, ADRBD_Forecast_Close_Date__c, Close_Date__c, Close_Month_Forecasted__c, Install_Date_Instruments_only__c, Opportunity__c, 
                          Opportunity_Name__c, Opp_Safe_ID__c, Quantity__c, Stage__c, Territory__c, Territory_Manager__c, Total_FS_Modules__c, Total_Instr_Revenue__c, Total_Price__c, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity_Snapshots__r)
                         FROM Opportunity    
                         WHERE (NOT Name LIKE 'Test')
                         AND (Account.BillingCountryCode = 'US' OR Account.BillingCountryCode = 'CA')
                         AND Forecastable__c = true
                         AND Forecasted_Close_Date_30_60_90__c <> null
                         ORDER BY Account.Name
                        ];

        // Creating Set to store unique values
        Set<String> monthSet = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> terrSet = new Set<String>();
        for (Opportunity o : opportunities){
            monthSet.add(o.Close_Month_Forecasted__c);
            terrSet.add(o.Account.Terr_From_Zip__c);
        }

        // Converting to List in order to sorth the results alphabetically
        List<String> monthList = new List<String>(monthSet);
        List<String> terrList = new List<String>(terrSet);
        monthList.sort();
        terrList.sort();


        closeDates = new String[monthList.size()];
        Integer i = 0;
        for(String month : monthList){
            closeDates[i] = month;
            i++;

        }

        terrs = new String[terrList.size()];
        Integer i2 = 0;
        for(String terr : terrList){
            terrs[i2] = terr;
            i2++;

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

**** VF PAGE ****

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastController" action="{!load}" sidebar="false"  tabStyle="Opportunity" docType="html-5.0">
    <style>
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;

        }

        th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 4px;

        }


        td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 4px;
        <!-- border-right: 1px solid black; -->
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #cccccc;}
    </style>


    <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunities" subtitle="Forecast Review"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!closeDates}" var="c" >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Close Date (Forecasted) {!c}" >

            <apex:repeat value="{!terrs}" var="t" >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Territory {!t}" >
                    <table>

                        <tr>

                            <th>Account Name</th>

                            <th>Territory</th>

                            <th>Territory Manager</th>

                            <th>Stage</th>

                            <th>Prev Stage</th>

                            <th>Opportunity Name</th>

                        </tr>

                        <apex:repeat var="opps" value="{!opportunities}">

                            <apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!IF(c=opps.Close_Month_Forecasted__c && t=opps.Account.Terr_From_Zip__c,true,false)}">

                                <tr>

                                    <td> {!opps.Account.Name} </td>

                                    <td>{!opps.Account.Terr_From_Zip__c}</td>

                                    <td> {!opps.Account.Territory_Manager__c} </td>

                                    <td>{!opps.StageName}</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(opps.Opportunity_Snapshots__r.size > 0,true,false)}">
                                            {!opps.Opportunity_Snapshots__r[0].Stage__c}
                                        </apex:outputText>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>{!opps.Name}</td>

                                </tr>

                            </apex:variable>

                        </apex:repeat> 

                    </table>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to structure your data into maps, so that you have more control on the Apex side; this will also greatly improve performance. Here's a modified version of the controller logic:

```
public class ForecastController {
    public Map<String, Map<String, List<Opportunity>>> values { get; set; }
    public class ForecastWrapper {
        public String closeMonth { get; set; }
        public String[] territories { get; set; }
    }
    public List<ForecastWrapper> forecasts { get; set; }

    public void load(){
        // Load all the data into a map
        values = new Map<String, Map<String, List<Opportunity>>>();
        for(Opportunity record:
                        [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Account.Territory_Manager__c, StageName, CloseDate, Forecastable__c, 
                        Forecasted_Close_Date_30_60_90__c, Close_Month_Forecasted__c, Account.Terr_From_Zip__c, 
                        (Select Id, Account_Name__c, ADRBD_Forecast_Close_Date__c, Close_Date__c, Close_Month_Forecasted__c, Install_Date_Instruments_only__c, Opportunity__c, 
                        Opportunity_Name__c, Opp_Safe_ID__c, Quantity__c, Stage__c, Territory__c, Territory_Manager__c, Total_FS_Modules__c, Total_Instr_Revenue__c, Total_Price__c, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity_Snapshots__r)
                        FROM Opportunity    
                        WHERE (NOT Name LIKE 'Test')
                        AND (Account.BillingCountryCode = 'US' OR Account.BillingCountryCode = 'CA')
                        AND Forecastable__c = true
                        AND Forecasted_Close_Date_30_60_90__c <> null
                        ORDER BY Account.Name
                        ]) {
            Map<String, List<Opportunity>> dateRange = values.get(record.Close_Month_Forecasted__c);
            if(dateRange == null) {
                values.put(record.Close_Month_Forecasted__c, dateRange = new Map<String, List<Opportunity>>());
            }
            List<Opportunity> territoryList = dateRange.get(record.Account.Terr_From_Zip__c);
            if(territoryList == null) {
                dateRange.put(record.Account.Terr_From_Zip__c, territoryList = new List<Opportunity>());
            }
            territoryList.add(record);
        }
        // Load the "keys" into our specified order
        forecasts = new ForecastWrapper[0];
        String[] months = new List<String>(values.keySet());
        months.sort();
        for(String month: months) {
            Map<String, List<Opportunity>> territoryList = values.get(month);
            String[] territories = new List<String>(territoryList.keySet());
            territories.sort();
            ForecastWrapper wrap = new ForecastWrapper();
            wrap.month = month;
            wrap.territories = territories;
            forecasts.add(wrap);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, the Visualforce page would use that wrapper instead:

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastController" action="{!load}" sidebar="false"  tabStyle="Opportunity" docType="html-5.0">

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunities" subtitle="Forecast Review"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!forecasts}" var="c" >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Close Date (Forecasted) {!c.month}" >

            <apex:repeat value="{!c.territories}" var="t" >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Territory {!t}" >
                    <table>

                        <tr>

                            <th>Account Name</th>

                            <th>Territory</th>

                            <th>Territory Manager</th>

                            <th>Stage</th>

                            <th>Prev Stage</th>

                            <th>Opportunity Name</th>

                        </tr>
                        <!-- access map variables -->
                        <apex:repeat var="opps" value="{!values[c][t]}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td> {!opps.Account.Name} </td>

                                    <td>{!opps.Account.Terr_From_Zip__c}</td>

                                    <td> {!opps.Account.Territory_Manager__c} </td>

                                    <td>{!opps.StageName}</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!opps.Opportunity_Snapshots__r.size > 0}">
                                            {!opps.Opportunity_Snapshots__r[0].Stage__c}
                                        </apex:outputText>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>{!opps.Name}</td>

                                </tr>

                            </apex:variable>

                        </apex:repeat> 

                    </table>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

---

This is only a quick hack--you may need additional work. However, it is my hope that this demonstration will at least get you started on the right path.

Note that this also solves a major performance bottleneck. If you have 10 territories with 10 months and 100 opportunities, your code previously needed 10,000 loop iterations, while the new code requires only a few hundred. You should see greatly improved performance. Also, this new design won't crash when you have more than 1,000 opportunities to display (total), but can instead handle tens of thousands of opportunities.

Comment: sfdcfox Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested in the controller and received the errors below. Any chance you can offer insight into fixing them?

Line 11 - Illegal assignment from Map<Date,Map<String,List<Opportunity>>> to Map<String,Map<String,List<Opportunity>>>

Line 40 - Duplicate variable: territories

Line 40 - Variable does not exist: territoryList

Line 41 - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sort() from the type Map<String,List<Opportunity>>

Line 44 - Illegal assignment from Map<String,List<Opportunity>> to List<String>

Comment: @GregM. Those were mostly copy-paste errors. Try the edited version.

Comment: the code changes you provided solved the errors that prevented me from saving. Now I am getting the following error on my VFP.

Map key ForecastWrapper:[month=2020/02, territories=(NW-01, NW-04)] not found in map
Error is in expression '{!values[c][t]}' in component <apex:repeat> in page axdxforecast

I am sure I was wrong in my attempt but I tried adding rendered="{!If(t == null, true, false)}"
this allowed the page to render and the appropriate close month / territories are being displayed, but there are no actual opportunity records to display. Any ideas?

Comment: any more ideas?